Calculate the contour integral $\oint_{|z| = 1.5} \frac{e^{-z^2}}{\sin(4z)} \, dz$ using the Residue problem.
I would like to evaluate the following contour integral:
$$\oint_{|z| = 1.5} \frac{e^{-z^2}}{\sin(4z)} \, dz$$
where $|z| = 1.5$ is the contour.
I have found that the function has singularities inside the countour at $0$, $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$.
However, I struggle to go from there.
I start trying to express the function as a Laurent series around $z=0$ (since it seems easiest), so I get:
$$\frac{e^{-z^2}}{\sin 4z} = \frac{(-z^2) + \frac{(-z)^2}{2} + \frac{(-z)^3}{6} + \frac{(-z)^4}{24} + \ldots}{4z - \frac{32 z^3}{3} + \frac{128 z^5}{15} + \ldots} $$
However, simplifying this seems quite difficult, and I have no idea how to do it.
Any insights or verification of my approach would be appreciated!

Please include your attempts of calculations of the residues, even if they failed.

Added how far I've come, I have tried to express as laurant series to find the residue, but failed.

You forgot $1+$ in the numerator, and expanding the series of the numerator is not necessary. So, $f(z)\sim\frac{e^0}{4z}$ as $z\to0$, hence the residue at $0$ is...

$\frac{1}{4}$ right? Since it's the first $z^{-1}$ term.

Right. Now do the same for $f(\pi/4+h)$ and $f(-\pi/4+h)$ as $h\to0$. Don't bother with the numerator: just take its (happily non-zero!) value for $h=0$.

Thank you!
Don't we do that when $f(-\pi/4 + h)$ approaches the singularity, eg $h → \pi/4$. Or why do we do it when it approaches $0$?

Hint $$ \text{Res}\bigg(\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)g(z)},z=a\bigg)=\frac{f(a)}{g(a)} $$
